# Why is Hounsfiled Unite converted image black after normalization?

Tags: python-3.x, normalization, medical-imaging, nifti

I am working with nifti images (CT scans) and when I normalize the Hounsfield Unit converted images, the output is just a full black image. My code to convert to HU scale is as follows:

```py
def transform_to_hu(img_data, img_obj): 
    
    slope = img_obj.dataobj.slope
    intercept = img_obj.dataobj.inter
    
    img_data[img_data >= 1200] = 0
    images = slope * img_data.astype(np.float64)
    images += np.float64(intercept)
    
    return np.array(images, dtype=np.float64)

hu_scans = transform_to_hu(img_data, img_obj)
```

And then I normalize the HU converted images using following function:

```py
def normalize(volume):
    level = 70 
    window = 200 
    
    max = level + window/2 
    min = level - window/2 
    volume = volume.clip(min,max)
    
    """Normalize the volume"""
    volume[volume < min] = min
    volume[volume > max] = max
    volume = (volume - min) / (max - min)
    volume = volume.astype("float32")
    return volume

normalized_image = normalized(hu_scans)
```

Why is output image black after normalization?

[image]

Comment: What is your pixel type?  It looks like you're normalizing to the range of 0-1.  If the pixel type is not floats, it'll all be zeroes.

Comment: pixel data type is float64

Comment: It could be your display method.  It could be assuming pixel intensities are on the 0-255 range, so 0-1 pixels will all look black.  Trying multiplying everything by 255 just to see.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `nibabel`, you can simply use the `get_fdata()` method to load the CT as a numpy array with `float64` dtype. If your Nifti headers are set correctly, it should [automatically apply](https://nipy.org/nibabel/nifti_images.html#data-scaling) slope and intercept scaling.

To window and normalize your array to `[0, 1]`, you can use the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure

def window(data: np.ndarray, lower: float = -125., upper: float = 225., dtype: str = 'float32') -> np.ndarray:
    """ Scales the data between 0..1 based on a window with lower and upper limits as specified. dtype must be a float type.

    Default is a soft tissue window ([-125, 225] ≙ W 350, L50).

    See https://radiopaedia.org/articles/windowing-ct for common width (WW) and center/level (WL) parameters.
    """
    assert 'float' in dtype, 'dtype must be a float type'
    clipped = np.clip(data, lower, upper).astype(dtype)
    # (do not use in_range='image', since this does not yield the desired result if the min/max values do not reach lower/upper)
    return skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(clipped, in_range=(lower, upper), out_range=(0., 1.))
```

Using PIL, you can get an image from your data by using:

```py
from PIL import Image

img = Image.fromarray((window(data[..., 55].T) * 255.).round().astype('uint8'))  # axial slice number 55
```